# Where is the error in my syntax? Getting values from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, syntax

I am trying to read an integer from a SQL Server database by text in comboboxes.
I get a "Syntax error" "near" my Table name "Seeweg". The debugger does not highlight the line, where the error happens.

The column with the value I like to get is named `seadistance`. The other columns, by which to sort are `start` and `ziel`.

They get sorted by the values written in the comboboxes.

To reproduce this procedure I inserted the code into a class and called the instance by a button named `btnSea`.

I already searched for similar problems, but I could not find any syntax errors concerning the string implementation. The column names are correct.

```
//The Button
private void btnSea_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Entnehmen CO2 = new Entnehmen();
            int Dist = CO2.Werte("Seeweg", "start", "ziel", "seadistance", comboSeaOrig.Text, comboSeaDest.Text);
            MessageBox.Show(Dist.ToString());
        }
```

```
//The class
class Entnehmen
{
        public int Werte(string Tabelle, string Reihe1, string Reihe2, string Wertereihe, string WertReihe1, string WertReihe2)
        {
            int Wert = 0;
            string myConnection = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

            using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(myConnection))
            {
                myConn.Open();
                SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT '" + Wertereihe + "' FROM '" + Tabelle + "' WHERE '" + Reihe1 + "' = '" + WertReihe1 + "' AND '" + Reihe2 + "' = '" + WertReihe2 + "' ; ", myConn);
                Wert = (int)SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            return Wert;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the value to be given back. Before that happens, I get the error:

> Incorrect syntex near 'Seeweg'

Where is the syntax mistake? Any help is appreciated =)

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `SqlCommand SelectCommand.CommandText`?

Comment: Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection .

Comment: Error indicates you have issue generating SqlCommand string. You can check what is generating there by printing the Script line you are creating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating something like:

```
SELECT 'seadistance' FROM 'Seeweg' WHERE 'start' = 'aa' AND 'ziel' = 'bbb'
```

This is not a valid T-SQL statement. Correct your quotes in columns and tables variables.

This is a suggestion of how you can write your T-SQL statemant based on your code:

```
SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + Wertereihe + " FROM " + Tabelle + " WHERE " + Reihe1 + " = '" + WertReihe1 + "' AND " + Reihe2 + " = '" + WertReihe2 + "' ; ", myConn);
```